# Getting grow heap when using BitmapFactory.decodeResource

Tags: android

I get the following warning:

```
Grow heap (frag case) to 15.723MB for 2073616-byte allocation
```

I am using this function (see below) to save a drawable to a file.

Is there a better way to save the image?

```
public void save(int resId) {
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inSampleSize = IMAGE_IN_SAMPLE_SIZE;
    options.inScaled = false;
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

    Bitmap bitmapImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), resId, options);

    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;
    try {
        fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(createFile());
        bitmapImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fileOutputStream);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (fileOutputStream != null) {
                fileOutputStream.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a smaller image. Put it in a better directory (depending on what `resId` is).

Comment: Yes, but than the quality gets bad.

Comment: Then do not complain about the memory usage. Or, stop packaging this content as a resource, and do something else to get the file (e.g., download it). 2073616 is about a 720 x 720 pixel image, and if you do not want to use a lower resolution, then it will take up 2073616 bytes of heap space as a resource.

Comment: And what do you mean by "put it in a better directory"?

Comment: I do not know where this resource is. For this use case, ideally it would be in `res/raw/` or `res/drawable-nodpi/`. If you put it in `res/drawable/`, that is equivalent to `res/drawable-mdpi/`, and the image will be resampled based on the actual screen density.

Answer (score 0):

try this.. adding to your applciation tag in AndroidManifest.xml

```
 android:largeHeap="true"
```